# Как добавить новые значения из одного массива в другой

Tags: javascript

Есть массивы A и B.
В них обоих содержатся объекты.
У каждого объекта есть `A[i].Key` и `B[i].Key`;
Собственно вопрос: 
 Как из массива `A` добавить те элементы в массив `B`, значения `Key` которых не содержатся в `B`.

Comment: Также забыл добавить - в А могут быть дубли (элементы с одинаковыми Key), в B же должен быть добавлен лишь один элемент (исключить появление дубликатов с одинаковыми Key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const A = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}];

const B = [{key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}];

B.push(...A.filter(el => !B.find(({key}) => el.key === key)));

console.log(B);
```

UP (дубли + древний JS):

```js
const A = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}];

const B = [{key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}];

A.forEach(function(elA){ 
    !B.filter(function(elB){ 
      return elA.key === elB.key
    }).length && B.push(elA); 
})

console.log(B);
```

Comment: Пишет - ({ Key }) не поддерживается в ECMAScript 5

Comment: Также забыл добавить - в А могут быть дубли (элементы с одинаковыми Key), в B же должен быть добавлен лишь один элемент (исключить появление дубликатов с одинаковыми Key)

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб не создавать новый массив(и не фильтровать) и не проверять каждый элемент, проверяем с помощью has(), только элементы B

```js
function union(a, b) {
  const end = b.length - 1
  const has = (key) => {
    let i = end
    while (i--) if (b[i].Key === key) return true
    return false
  }
  for (const item of a) {
    has(item.Key) || b.push(item)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если массивы большие, можно немного оптимизировать по времени ответ @Darth. Создадим вспомогательный `Set` с ключами из проверяемого массива, чтобы не приходилось обыскивать его в каждой итерации. Но нужно проверять для конкретного случая, чтобы время на создание `Set` не свело на нет дальнейший выигрыш.

```js
const A = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}];
const B = [{key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}];

const bKeys = new Set(B.map(({ key }) => key));

for (const el of A) {
  if (!bKeys.has(el.key)) B.push(el);
}

console.log(B);
```

Comment: Если массивы большие, то push() ограничен кол-вом аргументов. По крайне мере у меня на NodeV14 и в Chrome 130_000 элементов уже не вставить.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Да, точно. Заменил на код с циклом, тем более так мы сэкономим на одной вспомогательной структуре.

Comment: а я до `Set-а` не додумался, но проверял тоже только значения с последнего индекса `B` в обратном порядке до `0`

Comment: А тут не подойдет assign? Или я не так задачу прочитал.

Comment: @OliverPatterson assign, насколько я понимаю, подходит для слияния объектов, а не массивов.